# I unmasked my php-8.0-fpm service and now I get 502

Tags: php, nginx, server

After running systemctl unmask php8.0-fpm to be able to restart the php8.0-fpm my website start responding with a 502 code, the unmask command returned this output:

> Removed /etc/systemd/system/php8.0-fpm.service.

I got this on my logs *16 connect() to unix:/var/run/php/php8.0-fpm.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream.

I think my server was configured like suggested in this website https://ispire.me/running-php-fpm-with-different-user-group-using-umask/, but right now i dont have the php8.0-fpm.service on the /lib or the /etc since the unmask command removed this file.

Comment: Any 500 type errors are often difficult to find. Start by looking in the error log for clues

Comment: What exactly did you type? What was the umask command (umask or unmask?) and what did you type after that to restart php-fpm? Do you see any additional error messages in the server log?

Comment: You need to define pool for your php8.0 to run correctly. Then you need to make sure your Nginx connects to this / these php8.0 fpm pool(s).

Comment: A had this in my log: 2021/12/21 16:30:55 [crit] 2785546#2785546: *16 connect() to unix:/var/run/php/php8.0-fpm.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 185.191.171.39, server: _, request: "GET /noticia/stj-segunda-secao-decide-em-repetitivo-pela-legalidade-da-pactuacao-da-tac-e-tec-ate-2008 HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php8.0-fpm.sock:", host: "lbadiligencias.com.br"

Comment: Ingo Steinke - I used the unmask command and i restart the php8.0-fpm with sudo service php8.0-fpm restart